# Возникает проблема регулярного падения интерфейса Ethernet на плате SK-NUC976. В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded

Вывод команды "ifconfig":

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:00:01:92
      inet addr:192.168.0.136  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Вывод команды "ip link":

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
   link/ether 08:00:27:00:01:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: tunl0: <NOARP> mtu 0 qdisc noop
   link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

Чуть ранее при такой же аналогичной прошивке было так(работающая конфигурация, на ip не обращайте внимания, настроить это дело не проблема).
Вывод ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:00:01:92
      inet addr:192.168.0.136  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1477 errors:0 dropped:412 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:273157 (266.7 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Вывод из "ip link":

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
      link/ether 08:00:27:00:01:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 3: tunl0: <NOARP> mtu 0 qdisc noop
      link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

Причем кабель интерфейса никто не трогает. Переподключение кабеля решает проблему. Впрочем иногда проблема "самоустраняется"

Comment: попробуй переобжать

Comment: Да вот, прозвонили шнур, проблемы не нашли.

Comment: иногда не вшнуре деол а в контакте

Comment: Просто если это программная проблема, то я даже не знаю с чего начать, и как её обследовать

Comment: Ну вот сделали обжим. Это не исправило проблему

Comment: а в логах что в это время?

Comment: А как посмотреть логи?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - sudo journalctl -xn

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).